# Can I build snaps in linux mint 18.3?

Tags: snap

Can I build snaps in linux mint 18.3? In the snapcraft tutorial I read that they strong recommend ubuntu 16.04.3(LTS) and mint 18.3 is based on 16.04. is only Ubuntu necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From official [snapcraft install docs](https://docs.snapcraft.io/core/install-linux-mint):

> On Linux Mint snapd is available from the official repositories
>   starting with the 18.2 (Sonya) release.

So, you can it use.